# Firebase UserID Null Pointer Exception When passes Null Check

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep having an error where the user id from firebase is apparently a null object even though I made an if statement to check that it is not.
The error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.matthew.myapplication, PID: 18396
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matthew.myapplication/com.example.matthew.myapplication.cb}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.matthew.myapplication.cb.getGameList(cb.java:112)
       at com.example.matthew.myapplication.cb.onCreate(cb.java:69)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I don't understand how the error is happening when it shouldn't be. The snippets of code dealing with this:

```
public void getGameList(){
    Boolean isDone = false;
    int che = 0;
    if(uID != null) {
        while (isDone == false) {
            String sche = Integer.toString(che); //error is on this line at uID
            if (datas.child(uID).child("Game List").hasChild(sche)) {
                list.add(datas.child(datas.child(uID).child("Game List").child(sche).getValue().toString()).child("GAME NAME").getValue().toString());
                list.add(datas.child(datas.child(uID).child("Game List").child(sche).getValue().toString()).child("GAMEID").getValue().toString());
                che = che + 1;
            } else {
                isDone = true;
            }

        }
    }

}

user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    uID = user.getUid();

    cont = (Button) findViewById(R.id.con);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ret);
    game = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.games);

    list.add("Select a Game");
    list2.add("novalue");
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            datas = dataSnapshot;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

I also haven't had this issue before which is weird because I use this exact snippet in several other classes but it's only here where the problem arises.
Any help is appreciated, even if it's to a question that I missed when searching for an answer to this problem. Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `null` because you are using that `datas` outside the `onDataChange()` method. This is happening because onDataChange is called in an asynchronously way. It means that everything you do outside that method is executed before that `onDataChange()` method has been called. To solve this, move those statements inside the `onDataChange()` method and everythig will work fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have it that way in other sections and it works fine. The 'onDataChange()' is called before everything else in 'onCreate' The only time this problem occurs is that section and it's bothersome. I'll try it though.

Comment: The variable `datas` will be null until the onDataChange method actually assigns it. Where do you need that value? In a `DatabaseReference`? Just use it directly in `onDataChange()`.

Need something more complex, call a separate method from `onDataChange()` and pass in your parameters. If you want something even more complex, try synchronous code.

Comment: I need 'datas' to be called in a button click event. But to prevent this i'm using if statements to check that it isn't null first before proceeding.

Comment: Use it in `onDataChange()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
   ...

   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

   if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
      uID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
   }

   ...
}
```

I think this can solve your problem